# how to use two lines in button to display the two lines string value from two NSString variable

Tags: ios, objective-c

**how to use two lines in button to display the two lines string value from two NSString variable. I know how to use two lines in button like that:**

```
mybutton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    mybutton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [mybutton setTitle: @"Line1\nLine2" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

but I want to get data from two NSString variable. instead of using
 `@"Line1\nLine2"`
Can any one help me this .

Comment: whats your button frame, show the some OP

Comment: add this `mybutton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2` and check

Comment: just I want to use like this:  [mybutton  setTitle: @"%@\n%@" , onemb , twomb forState: UIControlStateNormal]; how to use this.

Comment: Mr  Anbu.karthik how to solve this please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your Code with button type as `Custom` and `system` also,

```
NSString *onemb = @"hi";
NSString *twomb = @"Welcome";
_myButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
_myButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
_myButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
[_myButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", onemb, twomb] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

I got the OP as

[image]

Comment: @user9713861 - which one you modified

Answer (score 0):

use `stringWithFormat` like this:

```
NSString* title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", onemb, twomb];
[myButton setTitle:title forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:

```
let firstLine = "first"
let secondLine = "second"
let button = UIButton()
button.setTitle(firstLine + "\n" + secondLine, for: .normal)
```